How many 5 digit palindromes are divisible by 4?
How many 5 digit palindromes are divisible by 4?
what I have figured out so far:
2abc2
4abc4
6abc6
8abc8
I haven't figured out a way to actually solve the problem yet

Hint: a number is divisible by $4$ if and only if its last two digits are divisible by $4$. (This is a well-known divisibility trick.)

That trick works because $100$ is divisible by $4$

I would think a palindrome has the form $2aba2$, $4aba4$ etc.

Oh right, that was a silly mistake

A number is divisible by 4 if, and only if its last two digit are (try proving it with modular arithmetic).
Let's construct such a number:
For the last two digits, we've got 25 choices:
$\{0, 4, .. ,96\}$ well not really, because our number must be a palindrome, the last digit is the same as the first, and we need it to be five digit long, so we shall take out every number that ends with a 0, which are: 0, 20, 40, 60 and 80. That leaves us with 20 choices.
We've got 10 choices for the middle man, namely 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
Finally, the first two digits are already imposed by our choice of the last two, so no more choices there.
Thus, there are $20\times 10 = 200$ 5-digit long palindromes.
